# How can I create in Django a custom absolute url for a predefined class

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I need to make a blog in Django and I have a `Blog` class declared as follows:

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter name')
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

The `User` class is a predefined Django class.

As you can see for Blogger I don't create a class but I use a default one from Django `class User`.
In the template `blog_list.html` I use the following line to display the blog author with a link to the author page:

**blog_list.html**

```
<a href="/blog/blogger/{{ blog.author.id }}">{{blog.author.first_name}} {{blog.author.last_name}}</a>
```

**wiews.py**

```
class BlogListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Blog
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 5

class BloggerDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
    path('blogs/', views.BlogListView.as_view(), name='blogs'),
    path('blogger/<int:pk>', views.BloggerDetailView.as_view(), name='blogger-detail'),
]
```

My question is how can I declare an `absolute_url` for `blog.author` to NOT use the manual constructed `/blog/blogger/{{ blog.author.id }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [*proxy model* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#proxy-models), this is not a new (real) model. Behind the curtains, it uses the `User` model, but it converts it to `Author` objects, and we can add logic to that `Author` object:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Author(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogger-detail', args=(self.pk,))
```

and then use that proxy model in the `ForeignKey` instead:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter name')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

then in the template, you use:

```
<a href="{{ blog.author.get_absolute_url }}">link</a>
```